# Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined .how solve this problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, microservices

I have written a CRUD using  node.js .I need to use another node project as a micro service.So i use the axios npm module for send http request to another node project.When i run the code  following error comes again and again.how to fix it.
this is my index.js file

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;
const express=require('express');

const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const mysqlConnection=require('./connections');
const cors = require('cors');
mysqlConn = mysqlConnection.startDBConnection();
// console.log(mysqlConn);



var app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const emp=require('./routes/employee')(express.Router(), mysqlConn);

app.use('/employeeDetails',emp);


app.listen(3001,()=>console.log('express server is working at port:3001'));
```

This is the routes files.
employee.js

```js
const apiAdapter = require('./apiAdapter');

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
const api = apiAdapter(BASE_URL);



module.exports = (router, mysqlConnection) => {

router.get('/employees/:id', (req, res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Id = ?', [req.params.Id], (err, rows, fields) => {
               if (!err)
                   res.send(fields);
               else
                   console.log(err);
            }) 

api.get('/checkAudtStatus',req.body)
.then(respond)
{

if(respond.data===true)
{
api.post('/createAuditRecord',req.body)
.then(respond)
{
res.send(res.data)
}
}
}  
})




router.post('/employees',(req,res)=>{

    emp = {
       "Id":req.body.Id,
       "Name":req.body.Name,
       "Age":req.body.Age,
       "Salary":req.body.Salary,
       "City":req.body.City 
    }
    mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO Employee SET ?",emp, function(err, result){
        //  //If err, callback false
        if(err){
            res.send(false);
            // res.send(false);
        }
        else{
            res.send(result);
        }
    })
    api.get('/checkAuditStatus',req.body)
    .then(respond)
    {
    
    if(respond.data===true)
    {
    api.post('/createAuditRecord',req.body)
    .then(respond)
    {
    res.send(res.data)
    }
    }
    } 
})
}
```

This is the apiAdapter.js

```js
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = (baseURL) => {
    //allowing to handle other micro-services' urls by gateway
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: baseURL,
    });
}
```

This is the connection.js

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

//startDBConnection method
function startDBConnection(){
    try{
        
        var mysqlConnection = mysql.createPool({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            connectionLimit:10,//port:'8080',
            password: '',
            database: 'Test',
            //multipleStatements: true
        });
       

        return mysqlConnection;
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

module.exports.startDBConnection = startDBConnection;
```

following error comes while i run the above code.

```js
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
/home/naoda/Documents/test_/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.use (/home/naoda/Documents/test_/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/naoda/Documents/test_/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (/home/naoda/Documents/test_/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/naoda/Documents/test_/index.js:17:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 2):

when executing the `app.use(bodyParser.json());` couldn't find the value for `bodyParser.json()`
so that **try executing** `app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}));`
**before executing** `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Answer (score 1):

In these two lines of code:

```
const emp=require('./routes/employee')(express.Router(), mysqlConn);

app.use('/employeeDetails',emp);
```

`emp` needs to be a middleware function (or a router will also work as a middleware function).  But, when you look into the details of your employee module, you export a function that, when called doesn't return anything.  So, `emp` is `undefined`.  Probably, what you need to return from `emp` is the router you're adding routes to.

It appears you also have a problem with how your `api.get().then()` code is declared too.  Combining those two fixes, would be like this:

```
const apiAdapter = require('./apiAdapter');

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000';
const api = apiAdapter(BASE_URL);

module.exports = (router, mysqlConnection) => {
    router.get('/employees/:id', (req, res) => {
        mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Id = ?', [req.params.Id], (err, rows, fields) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(fields);
            } else {
                // send some sort of error status
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
                return;
            }
        });

        api.get('/checkAudtStatus', req.body).then(respond => {
            if (respond.data === true) {
                api.post('/createAuditRecord', req.body).then(res => {
                    res.send(res.data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return router;
}
```

Other unrelated problems that also need fixing:

1. `api.get()` has no error handler if that promise rejects
2. You have a code path where you will try to call `res.send()` twice for the same request.  Once in the callback for your `mysqlConnnection.query()` and once in the `.then()` handler for `api.get().then()`
3. Same declaration problem with the `api.post().then()`.

Comment: Thank you for this reply and  i  supported me lot